Getting org.graalvm.polyglot.impl.AbstractPolyglotImpl: Provider com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotImpl could not be instantiated
I am working on upgrading my legacy project to spring boot 3.2.0 along with JDK 17. Below is my code:
ScriptEngineManager scriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine scriptEngine = scriptEngineManager.getEngineByName("graal.js");

but getting the below error:
Getting org.graalvm.polyglot.impl.AbstractPolyglotImpl: Provider com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotImpl could not be instantiated
earlier when it was spring boot 2.7, the above code was working fine, I have newly added two additional dependencies (org.graalvm.polyglot). What could be the issue or am I missing something?
Added dependencies and updated dependency version to:
graalvm.js: 23.0.0

Add js-scriptengine and org.graalvm.js:js like below
<properties>
    <graalvm.version>23.0.1</graalvm.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
    <artifactId>js-scriptengine</artifactId>
    <version>${graalvm.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
    <artifactId>js</artifactId>
    <version>${graalvm.version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

Reference: https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/java-examlpes/tree/master/graal-js
